# Ionic-App runs in debug mode but not as Standalone-App

Tags: android, cordova, http, ionic-framework, webpack.config.js

I have developed an Android-App with Ionic using the SDK android-26. The latest things I added where easy plugins for sound output and REST-Access. Beside that I added a webpack.config.js for the use of different environments. The build is  working with *ionic serve* and *ionic run android --livereload --consolelogs* After that I tried to run my android app with

> ionic cordova run android

that lead to the *white screen of death*. Other variants like 
*ionic cordova build android* and cleaning the cordova platform did't work, too. I have increased the number of seconds for the splashscreen-delay and  url-timeout in config.xml, too.. without results.

Does anyone know the reason for that?

Comment: Use Google chrome as debugger to see whats happend. Analyse the logcat outputs, also.

Comment: Are you able to start a new project (ex: `ionic start app2 tabs`) and have it run successfully with `ionic cordova run android`?  If so, then add one plugin at a time and see where it fails...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. After starting a new project and failing again, I started to integrate my own components in parts. There I found a service whitch implemeted itself